# Regular expression for 10 numeric digits

Tags: regex

10 numeric digits, may be in the following formats: 123-4-567890, 1234-567890 or 1234567890

What is the regular expression for above digits?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: `\d(?:-?\d){9}` or `^\d(?:-?\d){9}$`

Comment: have you tried some code before

Comment: Downvoting because you haven't shown any research effort and you haven't tagged what language you're using as per the [tag:regex] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you mean any digit, 0-9, should be found if (and only if) it meets the three formats you presented, one regex that would work is

```
(([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{1}-[0-9]{6})|([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{6})|([0-9]{10}))
```

The above breaks down to three separate patterns, one for each case you presented, separated by regex's equivalent of "or", the `|` character. Each of the statements above contains `[0-9]`, a character class which will match any digit. Following each character class is a `{n}` statement, which means "repeat the previous item n times".

Disclaimer, there is probably a cleverer way to do this with a shorter pattern, but my regex-foo isn't quite that advanced yet